# Flutter ontap function runs when initiated

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code in my index file:

```
  _ontapd(_navigationLink,BuildContext context){
    print(_navigationLink);
  }
ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          itemCount: pages.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ProfileCard(pages[index],_ontapd(_navigations[index],context));
          }),
```

And this code in "ProfileCard" widget:

```
  String cardText;
  Function _onTapFunc;
  ProfileCard(@required this.cardText, this._onTapFunc);


GestureDetector(
          onTap: _onTapFunc,
...
)
```

Now whenever I refresh the app, the _onTapFunc gets called for each item in the pages list. Why does this happen?

Comment: Try `callback` instead of `Function` parameter.

Comment: @Sukhi it says no such class as callback. I tried VoidCallback, the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being called because you're calling it in your `itemBuilder`. It's odd that you're not getting a static analysis error here.

In the line `return ProfileCard(pages[index],_ontapd(_navigations[index],context));`, you're *calling* the `_ontapd` method. Note the parentheses, this means you're calling the method and passing the **return value**, not passing a reference to it. This value is then being passed to the `ProfileCard`.

To fix this you need to remove the parentheses. Just pass `_ontapd`

```
return ProfileCard(pages[index],_ontapd);
```

This does result in other issues however. `onTap` does not have the same parameters your `_ontapd` method requires, so it cannot be used without modification.

In your current implementation `_ontapd` just prints the first parameter passed to it, it doesn't even use the second parameter. So a better solution here would be to pass the value of `_navigationLink` to `ProfileCard` and define the `onTap` to print that value. `_ontapd` could then be completely removed

```
onTap: () {
  print(parameterPassed);
}
```

The example you provide may be simplified, in which case you hopefully have enough understanding of the error to come to a solution yourself or you'll have to provide more details.